# Callback just before session timeout after inactivity in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-timeout

I am using Devise Timeoutable feature for session timeout with Rails 6.

I want to delete a token just before the session timeout incase of inactivity from the database.

Is there a way to call a method just before session timeout ?

EDITED:

I have multiple applications and SSO as main application which handles login as well as jwt token.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to delete expired tokens in a background job or the next request?

Comment: Actually I have multiple applications and a SSO application as well which handles all the login and token stuffs. So on timeoutable, I want to delete the token from database, because it is created by JWT. And I have not set the expiry on the token as the session can still be active.

Comment: The timeout is passive, so there's no event. There is nothing happening at "the time of timeout", devise will just check the expiration vs. current time, when there's a new request, which could be days later. You could try to hook into that, but that wouldn't make much sense. 
Can't you set the same expiration on t he JWT as on the session?

Comment: @MarianTheisen... If we set JWT expiry, then it will expire after that certain time. But if the user uses the application, the session timeout would go beyond that JWT expiry. So JWT would expire but session is not.